# getopt for an optional command line argument of type "--my-option" in C

Tags: c, getopt

Basically the title. I've been reading the manual pages and can't seem to make it work. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us some code?

Comment: `getopt()` is just for traditional 1-character options. You have to use `getopt_long()` for long option names.

Comment: I was trying to use the `argp.h` module but `getopt_long` is much easier. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getopt_long()` for function names.

A detailed explanation is given [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt).

Thanks @Barmar for the suggestion!